# Aesthetically Pleasing String Replace Statement

Tags: powershell

I currently have code that looks like this:

```
$onestr = $twostr -replace "one","two" -replace "uno","dos"
```

I would like to format it like this:

```
$onestr = $twostr -replace "one","two" 
                  -replace "uno","dos"
```

such that the replace statements stack on top of each other.

I could use backtic as the line continuation character, but other stackoverflow questions cover why that is not a good idea.

I tried code that looks like this:

```
$onestr = ($twostr -replace "one","two" 
                   -replace "uno","dos"
          )
```

But I got an error that the paren is not matched.

My actual code has several replace statements (not just two).

Comment: Hey PowerShell team, can I get a `#requires -Semicolons`?

Comment: @BaconBits https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Comment: As written, the replace operations will replace string in the middle of words, e.g. "Hone the knife" becomes "Htow the knife"!   Is that desirable?    A whole different approach might be needed to get "whole word" semantics.

Comment: The whole-word idea can be achieved by wrapping the word with '\b' in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of replacements, what about a different approach which allows much more scope for the aligning of the replacement pairs nicely, without affecting the block of replace code.

```
$onestr = 'one thing uno thing'


$Pairs = @{ 
    'one' = 'two'
    'uno' = 'dos'
}

$Pairs.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { 
    $onestr = $onestr -replace $_.Name, $_.Value
}

$onestr
```

Answer (score 2):

This is less common, maybe awful, but more exactly the layout you ask about - using the .Net framework string replace method instead of the PowerShell operator.

```
$onestr = 'one thing uno thing'

$onestr.
    Replace('one', 'two').
    Replace('uno', 'dos')
```

Comment: I think you could probably edit this into your current answer ;)

Comment: @briantist but I want my current answer to be upvoted as a wordy but clean solution, and I expect this to be downvoted and criticised as unreadable, surprising and confusing. They should totally be different answers, maybe posted anonymously as someone else ;)

Comment: Well I can't oblige that, so here's a +1 in defiance!

Comment: I did not mention it in my original question, but I need to use -replace rather than .Replace because -replace is case insensitive.  Because I code in Java I prefer the .Replace() syntax.  However, in this case I agree that it is not good.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `$onestr = $twostr.Replace(...)` to get the same behavior as the OQ?

Comment: @Eris yes, you're right. (Why does `$twostr` have the "one"s in it and `$onestr` have the replaced "two"s in it?)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a backtick `` ` `` as a line continuation character, then I suggest you just make these separate statements:

```
$onestr = $twostr -replace "one","two" 
$onestr = $onestr -replace "uno","dos"
```

Answer (score 1):

An athletically, not aesthetically, pleasing method, more obvious than a backtick, might be a comment:

```
$onestr = $twostr -replace "one","two" <#
               #> -replace "uno","dos" <#
               #> -replace "foo","bar"
```

At least it's [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)er than repeating the assignments!

---

Or the heavy artillery: .NET Regex.Replace with a scriptblock so that the text is iterated only once:

```
function translate(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string]$text,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [hashtable]$map,

    [switch]$caseSensitive
) {
    $options = if ([bool]$caseSensitive) { '' } else { '(?i)' }
    ([regex]($options +
         ($map.Keys -replace '[$^*?.+|()\[\]{}\\]', '\$&' -join '|')
    )).Replace($text, { param([string]$match) $map[$match] })
}

'Abc' | translate -map @{
    'a'='1'
    'b'='2'
    'c'='3'
}
```

It's case-INsensitive by default.

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: I've added a single-pass plain-text replacement method. Haven't benchmarked it but theoretically could be faster than multi-pass replacements.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a **metafunction** with a [scriptblock] parameter to unwrap your expression into one line without any backticks.   For example, a simple `Invoke-Unwrap` metafunction could be used to define `ConvertTo-Spanish` as follows:*

```
function Invoke-Unwrap( [scriptblock]$sb) {
    Invoke-Expression ($sb -replace '\r?\n\s*-', ' -')
}

Invoke-Unwrap {
    function script:ConvertTo-Spanish( [string]$str ) { 
        $str 
            -replace "one","uno"
            -replace "two","dos" 
            -replace "thing","lo"
    }
}

ConvertTo-Spanish "thing one and thing two"
```

As written `Invoke-Unwrap` is very general, it allows word-wrapping before any operator or switch starting with a "-".   It could be expanded to allow other operator-characters at the beginning of a line, permitting arithmetic expressions to be written in a word-wrapped form.  I'm thinking `($sb -replace '\r?\n\s*([-+*/])', ' $1')`.

Or, if you want, you can enhance the processing of the string passed to Invoke-Expression to make your own little domain-specific language, perhaps implementing something more SED like.

- Apologies for my limited knowledge of Spanish... :-)